# Условие для ввода

Tags: java, android, kotlin

При входе в приложение стоит пинкод, хочу сделать следующую зависимость:

От кол-ва введенных неверных пинкодов, увеличивать период ожидания ввода для следующего.
Как обозначить сами попытки пользователя(под попытками понимаю что пользователь ввёл один раз пароль, другой раз пароль)?

На данный момент у меня следующий код

```
override fun passcodeCheckResult(correct: Boolean) {
    if (correct) {
        finish()
    } else {
        pincodeIsIncorrect()
    }
}
```

Метод pincodeIsIncorrect() очищает поле пинкода и выдаёт ошибку:

```
private fun pincodeIsIncorrect() {
    passcodeLabelView.clearAll()
    showWarning(R.string.error)
}
```

Comment: Что значит `обозначить сами попытки пользователя`? Пока вопрос непонятен.

Comment: @post_zeew обновил вопрос, ну то есть условие типо if user ввёл пинкод 10 раз, тогда он будет ждать ввода 5 минут до следующего ввода. Примерно такая идея.

Comment: А в чем, собственно, проблема написать что то вроде `tryingСount++`?

Comment: @rjhdby проблема в том что не совсем понимаю как считывать кол-во вводимых попыток пользователем.

Comment: var tryingСount = 0; 
override fun passcodeCheckResult(correct: Boolean) {
    tryingСount++;
    if (correct) {
        finish()
    } else {
        pincodeIsIncorrect()
    }
}

Comment: @rjhdby а с чего вы взяли что tryingСount это так раз таки кол-во вводимых попыток? Ну то есть как вы их считываете?

Comment: За ради душевного спокойствия буду считать, что вы просто очень странно сформулировали вопрос... У вас метод `passcodeCheckResult` что делает? Проверяет, правильно ли введен пин. Каждый раз проверяет, когда его ввели. Вот 1 раз ввели - переменная будет равна 1. Два раза ввели - переменная станет равна 2.

Comment: @Inkognito Сохраняй количество неверных попыток и умножай на константу, полученную величину прибавляй к System.currentTimeMillis() и сохраняй как время после которого доступна следующая попытка.
правда это не спасет от отката даты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто при каждом вводе инкрементировать специальную переменную.

```
var tryingCount = 0
override fun passcodeCheckResult(correct: Boolean) {
    tryingCount++
    if (correct) {
        finish()
    } else {
        pincodeIsIncorrect()
    }
}
```

Comment: я лично тоже не понимаю Вашу логику) автору нужно как то считывать ввод с клавиатуры и в зависимости от этого увеличивать время ожидания) то что делаете Вы, мне непонянто, но и автор тоже выдал какой то метод pincodeIsIncorrect() который ничего не объясняет, что он делает и вообще, ровно также как и Ваша переменная tryingCount.

Comment: @Morozov ответ я написал, чтобы в комментах код не постить. Так-то по имени метода видно, что он вызывается после каждого ввода пина. Собственно это вполне логичное место для вставки счетчика. А так-то да, постановка вопроса несколько смущает

Comment: @rjhdby обновил вопрос, получается что в условие else я могу дальше использовать в else ещё пару условий типо если tryingCount = 2 тогда ожидать время или как?

Comment: @Inkognito да, конечно. Логика именно в создании счетчика попыток ввода и его последующем использовании там, где вам нужно

Comment: с таким алгоритмом можно просто выйти из приложения, а потом опять начинать вводить и не ждать никакого времени. Счетчик нужно сохранять куда то вроде преференсов и обнулять при правильном вводе, заодно это убережет и от изменения даты по варианту, предложенному в коментариях

Comment: @rjhdby тогда последняя загвоздка будет в том, чтобы после if(tryingCount == 5) { проставить время ожидания} ?

Comment: @pavlofff да, уже решил вопрос с SP, спасибо за замечание.

Comment: @rjhdby получается нужно создавать какой то waiter? или можно сделать как то попроще?

Comment: @Inkognito например таймером воспользуйтесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258066/java-run-a-function-after-a-specific-number-of-seconds , только не забудьте вывести надпись "подождите N секунд", дабы не сильно икалось от проклятий пользователей

Comment: @rjhdby ну тут каждый раз одно и то же время, да и как-то слишком много кода, Вам не кажется?

Comment: @rjhdby Thread.sleep(4000); для этих целей не подойдёт?

Comment: @Inkognito да в общем что угодно подойдет, но это уже совершенно другой и достаточно глубокий вопрос, через комменты его не стоит решать